# I need to add label/text on top of that 100% box or some text next to the box to show some indication

Tags: r

I need to show 100% target or 80% target instead of just showing the numbers. Is there anyway to do this . I am new to this highcharter package. I need more information regarding this.

```
 library(lubridate)
    library(tidyverse)
    
    N <- 6
    set.seed(1234)
    
    df <- tibble(
      start = sort(Sys.Date() + months(2 + sample(10:20, size = N))),
      end = start + months(sample(1:3, size = N, replace = TRUE)),
      name = c("Import", "Tidy", "Visualize", "Model", "Transform", "Communicate"),
      id = tolower(name),
      dependency = list(NA, "import", "tidy", "tidy", "tidy", c("visualize", "model", "transform")),
      completed = c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.6, 0.9, 0)
    )
    
    df <- mutate_if(df, is.Date, datetime_to_timestamp)
    
    highchart(type = "gantt") %>% 
      hc_add_series(
        name = "Program",
        data = df
      ) %>% 
      hc_rangeSelector(enabled = TRUE) %>% 
      hc_navigator(
        enabled = TRUE,
        series = list(
          type = 'gantt',
          pointPlacement = 0.5,
          pointPadding =  0.25
        ),
        yAxis = list(
          min = 0,
          max = N,
          reversed = TRUE,
          categories = c()
        )
      )
```

Comment: This highcharter is based on JS

Comment: No. I want it in R . But this package was done originally for JS

Comment: OK - so, you dont' want JS, don't tag JS :p